# Word for words with close/similar spellings

Tags: meaning, orthography

I am working on [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) and I try to explain the concept.
Is there a word that means that 2 words are "close graphically speaking".

I found homophone, or homogragh, but these words are not the one I am looking for.

edit : homophone can be used with relatively "long distance" words : 'close' and 'clothes' (are up to three character away). However 'take' and 'make' are 1 character away but not homophones.

edit : homograph is used for exact (visually) same word with different meaning

Comment: in two words you can use [edit distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance) - it's more of a mathematical concept than a linguistic one

Comment: What do you mean by "close graphically speaking"?  Why doesn't  homograph fit?

Comment: Could you just stick with Levenshtein distance?  Near rhymes?  Of course, cognates are close to the ear, not identical to the eye.

Answer (score -2):

From Oxford:
https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/paronomasia

In general, paronomasia other that homographic and homophonic includes the  juxtaposition of words with small graphical differences. So you can say the two words are paranomasial